# Tricky MySQL JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a text input which upon keyup I want to update the options in an adjacent select field.

I have these 2 tables in my database:

**Models:**

```
ID  modelName  brandID
1   NA140           3
1   SRL             1
1   SRS             1
1   SRF             1
1   SMS             2
1   SMU             2
```

**Brands:**

```
ID  brandName
1    Samsung
2    Bosch
3    Panasonic
```

In the select field I want to list all the `brandNames` from the brands table but list them in relevance to the text input. 
So if 'SR' is typed the order of `modelNames` would be SRF, SRL, SRS, SMU, SMS, NA140 and then the corresponding `brandName` grabbed as the result but only list each brand once.

How would I write this query?

I have this basic idea which I think is what I need...

```
JOIN models & brands ON m.brandID = b.ID

MATCH modelName to string%

SELECT UNIQUE brandName
```

Comment: If SR is typed, should NA140 still be listed as a modelName? Why (because NA140 does not contain SR)?

Comment: What is the desired outcome in tabular form for the query?

Comment: @Joeseph B - The user will begin to type a model number within a text input and on each keyup it will pull data with ajax. This data will populate a select field with all the brand names from my brands table but will order them so the top option is the best match to the model number being typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.brandName 
FROM brands b 
JOIN models m 
ON m.brandID = b.id 
WHERE m.modelName LIKE '%$variable%' 

UNION 
SELECT b.brandName 
FROM brands b 
JOIN models m 
ON m.brandID = b.id 
WHERE m.modelName NOT LIKE '%$variable%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think is to first do a select on where it matches the user input, get those results, then do it again where it does, and combine the results with a union, like so:

```
(SELECT `t1`.`modelName`, `t1`.`brandID`,`t2`.`brandName` FROM `Models` as `t1` INNER JOIN `Brands` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`brandID`=`t2`.`ID` WHERE `t1`.`modelName` LIKE 'SR%' ORDER BY `t1`.`modelName`,`t2`.`brandName`)
UNION
(SELECT `t1`.`modelName`, `t1`.`brandID`,`t2`.`brandName` FROM `Models` as `t1` INNER JOIN `Brands` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`brandID`=`t2`.`ID` WHERE `t1`.`modelName` NOT LIKE 'SR%' ORDER BY `t1`.`modelName`,`t2`.`brandName`)
```

There may be a more efficient way to do this, this is what I could think of before I head out to the store :)

Comment: You can just select the data in general and sort the resulting set in your server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT brandname
  FROM models m JOIN brands b
    ON m.brandid = b.id
 ORDER BY modelname LIKE 'S%' DESC,
          modelname LIKE 'SR%' DESC,
          modelname
```

Output:

```
| BRANDNAME |
|-----------|
|   Samsung |
|     Bosch |
| Panasonic |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d482a/10)** demo

**UPDATE:** For `SMU%` input string the query should look

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT brandname
  FROM models m JOIN brands b
    ON m.brandid = b.id
 ORDER BY modelname LIKE 'S%' DESC,
          modelname LIKE 'SM%' DESC,
          modelname LIKE 'SMU%' DESC,
          modelname
```

Output:

```
| BRANDNAME |
|-----------|
|     Bosch |
|   Samsung |
| Panasonic |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d482a/38)** demo

Comment: This is what I am after! My string will be avariable from the user input so I would just need it like so
`code
SELECT DISTINCT brandname
  FROM models m JOIN brands b
    ON m.brandid = b.id
 ORDER BY modelname LIKE 'S%' DESC,
          modelname
`

And 'S%' would be 'variable%'
I tested this with a few different strings and all is ok apart from when I use 'SMU%' The output has 'Panasonic at the top where it should be 'Bosch' Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Take a look at the update. You'll have to dynamically build `ORDER BY` clause  depending on the length of the input string. Given your sample data Bosch will always be at the top.

Comment: I only need one string to be LIKE. this will be a variable sent from the user input on each keypup. I have posted the code I am using as an answer which works perfectly. I will mark as best answer when I am allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a similar query (simplified):

```
select brandName from (
select b.brandName as brandName, m.modelName 
from brands b join models m 
on m.brandid = b.id 
where m.modelName like '%sr%'
union
select b.brandName as brandName, m.modelName 
from brands b join models m 
on m.brandid = b.id 
where m.modelName not like '%sr%') as curb
group by brandName
```

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593b36/30

(Not exact naming of brands and models)

Comment: This is more like what I need. But I would need 'SELECT DISTINCT b.brandName' without the modelName output

Comment: I improved my answer although I think you all want the modelNames

Comment: This version doesn't have any effect when you change the LIKE string

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct brandName 
from Models m inner join Brands b
on m.brandID = b.ID
where m.modelName like 's%'
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c231/5)**

Comment: This only shows the brands of models that match the LIKE. I want all brands to output but have the best match at the top of the output.

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is a function to calculate the distance between the value in the field, anchor, and the values in the table, this function can be the difference between the `HEX` of the anchor and the `HEX` of the table values.

```
SELECT m.id, modelName, brandName
FROM   Model m
       INNER JOIN Brand b ON m.brandID = b.ID
ORDER BY ABS(CONV(HEX(RPAD('SR', 5, ' ')), 16, 10) 
           - CONV(HEX(RPAD(modelName, 5, ' ')), 16, 10))
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a87be7/2)</kbd>

Before passing the values to `HEX`, to have the correct result, the string need to be padded so that they all have the same length, that why there is a `RPAD`.

To calculate the difference the values are converted from base-16 to base-10, as the distance is only positive `ABS` is used.

If there are model with name longer than five char the parameter of the `RPAD` need to be  modified to the length of the longest model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the solution shouldn't be in the query part... at least for each letter typed. Maybe you could do one query for the first letter, retrieve the data for that letter into the client part, put the names in an array, and order in the client side.
Doing it in the server side is obviously slower, but making a query per each letter typed, taking into account how many times users type wrong letters, delete (would make a new query), and type again (new query), is terrible in terms of performance.
Putting the calculations in the client's side is much better. you could redo the query only if the first letter has been deleted and typed a new one.
May be you need some why to make new queries each time, but.. maybe a different approach cab help finding a better solution...

Comment: My database is very small and for now the efficiency isn't an issue. Once I have completed my site I may come back to this and re work it in this way =)